# JSF-pages are not affected by Eclipse's refactoring function

Tags: eclipse, jsf-2, refactoring

When I do refactoring in my backing beans, the xhmtl-files are not affected and JSF's EL-expression point into nowhere.

Answer (score 1):

You need to manually ensure that your XHTML el expressions point to your managed bean properties and methods. If you refactor a managed bean, then you should check any XHTML fragments that use that managed bean. As far as I know there's nothing that ties the two together automatically

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
Really, no automated refactoring? Eclipse is even able to find a bean's references (as EL) in xhtml-files. Automated refactoring would seem a not that much more expensive feature.

Answer (score 1):

Currently I use Eclipse Kepler with Jboss JSF plugin and it does that. I refactor field and check "rename getter" and "rename setter" , after that EL-expressions in .xhtml pages also got renamed[image: eclipse]

Comment: I think that works to a certain level, like when you change a field name of a bean. But if the bean has an attribute that is an object and you change the name of an attribute of that object, the EL-expression you access that attribute with (via the bean) won't get changed.
Anyway the is already more refactoring than I realized before your answer. Thank you.